# Inserting data: see which column causes numeric overflow on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with ~1000 columns that I am trying to insert into an empty table.  All of the columns are numeric except for an identifier.

I've written a create table statement something like this:

```
create table xx as (
  id varchar(10), 
  a numeric(9,4), 
  b numeric(9,4), 
  c numeric(5,4), 
  d numeric(5,4)
)
```

Then inserting like

```
insert into xx select * from yy
```

I get an error: something like "ERROR: XX000: Numeric data overflow (result precision)". I guess that I need to increase the precision of one of the columns- but which one? How can I tell? I'm using Aginity if it helps.

I have too many columns to test one by one. Space is also important, so I'm reluctant to increase the precision of all the columns.

Comment: are you using the copy command? if so then change all columns (temporarily) to be varchar then run some sql to check where your data errors are. Also I suggest you rethink your table design if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to test the columns one-by-one -- unless Redshift has some logging mechanisms that I haven't discovered.

You can construct the query using a spreadsheet. That is, start with a list of columns and then generate a query such as:

```
select min(a), max(a),
       min(b), max(b),
       . . .
from yy;
```

By the way, it is quite possible that your problem is simply based on doing the `insert` with no column names. You could first try:

```
insert into xx (id, a, b, c, d, . . .)
    select id, a, b, c, d, . . .
    from yy ;
```